# Velocity of Non-relativistic Electron

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, energy, kinematics

I am working on the course [MIT Quantum Physics I, Spring 2016](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/8-04-quantum-physics-i-spring-2016/). I am stuck in the following problem:

**Question:** In a classical universe, we might try to build a hydrogen atom by placing an electron in a circular orbit around a proton. We know that a non-relativistic accelerating electron radiates energy at a rate given by the Larmor formula: $$\frac{dE}{dt} = \frac{-2e^2a^2}{3c^3}$$ where $e$ is the electron charge and $a$ is the electrons acceleration. Electron potential energy in the presence of the proton is $V = \frac{-e^2}{r}$ and the magnitude of the force of attraction is $\frac{e^2}{r^2}$.

(a) Show that for a non-relativistic electron thhe energy $\Delta E$ lost per revolution is small compared to the electron's kinetic energy $K$. Hence, it is possible to regard the orbit as circular at any instant, even though the electron eventually spirals into the proton.

(b) A good estimate for the size of the hydrogen atom is $50$pm and a good estimate for the size of the nucleus is $1$fm. Compare the classicaly calculated velocity of the electron to the velocity of light at an orbital radius of $50$pm, $1$pm and $1$fm.

**My Attempt:** I believe I answered part (a). However, for part (b) I am stuck. I thought I need to use the usual kinetic energy formula to do that $K = \frac{1}{2}mv^2$. However, we do not know what the kinetic energy is. Since, in part (a) it is shown that radiation is negligible, I need to use potential energy and force of attraction to compute the kinetic energy?

Also, I am a mathematics phd student, however even my basic conceptual understanding of physics is bad. Thus, I really appreciate a comment which focus on the underlying ideas rather than the calculations itself.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Since, in part (a) it is shown that radiation is negligible, I need to use potential energy and force of attraction to compute the kinetic energy?"  Yes.